Telerik ReportViewer print is not working

After refresh

Hosted telerik report app in aws server(1 and 2 with LB)
Telerik report print in not working
If i refresh the page again and again sometimes it is loading
error message =  Client with ID 'b1a861a3eb2' not found. Expired.
Can someone suggest me on how to resolve this issue

Have you tried the two solutions at the bottom of this page?

Yes tried,

